# Interlinking "Organization" and "worksFor" microdata?

Tags: schema.org, microdata

We have a website where the contact page consists of two sections: first, information about the organisation (name, phone, e-mail, registration code), and second, the contact list of all workers (with name, position, e-mail and phone number).

I can add microdata to various fields without any problem. But I would also like to **interlink Organization and Person microdata with each other**. So that for Persons, "worksFor" itemprop information is taken directly from the Organization itemprop="name", and later on, that under the Organization the workers are listed with "employees" or "worker" itemprop.

```
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization">
    <span itemprop="name">Organization XXX</span>
    <span itemprop="telephone">1234567</span>
    <span itemprop="email">orgemail@org.org</span>
    <span id="worklink" itemprop="worksfor">Organization YYY</span>
</div>
    <table>
        <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="worklink">
            <td itemprop="name">Helmut York</td>
            <td itemprop="jobTitle">Analyst</td>
            <td itemprop="email">helmut@org.org</td>
        </tr>

        <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="worklink">
            <td itemprop="name">Julius Xing</td>
            <td itemprop="name">Analyst</td>
            <td itemprop="email">julius@org.org</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

However, the problem is that with this code, the Organization is also given "worksFor" itemprop, and of course, this gives an error in Google Structured Data Testing Tool. Any ideas how to solve this? The itemref attribute is very poorly documented in schema.org.

Comment: Or is it just easier to add `<meta itemprop="name" content="Organization XXX">`? However, this kind of defies the whole idea of itemref and as far as I've read, Google does not like hidden content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the **`itemref` attribute**, but you have to move `id="worklink"` and `itemprop="worksFor"`¹ to the element which should be added as property value.

So it could look like this:

```html
<div itemprop="worksFor" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" id="worklink">
</div>

<table>
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="worklink"></tr>
  <tr itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemref="worklink"></tr>
</table>
```

But now you have to make sure that the `Organization` item has no other Microdata item as parent, otherwise it would be added via the `worksFor` property to this item, too.

An alternative to `itemref` would be to use the `itemid` attribute and reference the organization URI as value, but it might not be supported by every consumer.

¹ Note that URIs are case-sensitive. The property is [`ẁorksFor`](http://schema.org/worksFor), not `worksfor`.

Comment: OK, thanks for the reply. However two issues: a) this way the "Organization" tab is completely lost in G test tool - so how to retain both "Organization" and "Persons"? b) and although "Persons" are now linked with the organization, it shows after "worksFor [Organization]:" a line in italics "http://www.example.com/worklink", which I guess is a kind of error?

Comment: @Kristjan: **b)** Yes, that’s an error in the Google SDTT (they interpret the `id` attribute like the `itemid` attribute, but that’s not correct per the Microdata spec). **a)** If using `itemref` (or more precise: if using an `Organization` item as value for `worksFor`), that’s not possible. The `Organization` item is not lost, it’s just not displayed on the top-level (as it’s no longer a top-level Microdata item), but nested under the `Person` items. -- If you want it the other way around, you could use the [`employee`](http://schema.org/employee) property instead.